# Isometric Spherical Space Forms

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, reference-request, isometry

I have seen the following "theorem" stated in any places, but haven't been able to find a proof of it:

> Theorem: Two spherical space forms $S^{2n-1}/G_1$ and $S^{2n-1}/G_2$ are isometric iff $G_1$ and $G_2$ are orthogonal in O(2n).

Can anyone please share a proof of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think the word you want is ***conjugate***, not "orthogonal." (I don't know what it means for subgroups of $O(2n)$ to be "orthogonal.")

A more general version of the theorem you're looking for is proved, for example, in Joe Wolf's [Spaces of Constant Curvature](https://books.google.com/books?id=8qoJBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=wolf+constant+curvature&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimxK717fvQAhXoylQKHQOhDo8Q6AEIGjAA):

> **Lemma 2.5.6:** *Let $P\colon L\to M$ and $Q\colon L\to N$ be universal pseudo-Riemannian coverings. Let $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ be the respective groups of deck transformations. Then $M$ and $N$ are isometric if and only if $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are conjugate subgroups of the group of all isometries of $L$.*

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I meant to write conjugate, but was thinking about isometries lifting to isometries on $S^n$ in the orthogonal group, so typed "orthogonal" by mistake.